# In R, rbind dataframes repeting only some elements

Tags: r, rbind

I have 4 dataframes (df, df1, df2 and df4) and I want to create df3.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Date = c("28/04/2010", "26/09/2010"),
  HolidayType = c("MUNICIPAL", "MUNICIPAL"),
  State = c("AC", "MG"),
  Municipality = c("Acrelândia", "Belo Horizonte")) 
df1 <- data.frame(
  Date = c("18/03/2010", "16/01/2010"),
  HolidayType = c("ESTADUAL", "ESTADUAL"),
  State = c("AC","MG"),
  Municipality = c("NA", "NA"))                                                                      
df2 <- data.frame(
  Date = c("10/05/2010", "22/11/2010"),
  HolidayType = c("NACIONAL", "NACIONAL"),
  State = c("NA", "NA"),
  Municipality = c("NA", "NA"))
df4 <- data.frame(
  Date = c("05/07/2010", "07/09/2010"),
  HolidayType = c("OPTIONAL", "OPTIONAL"),
  State = c("NA", "NA"),
  Municipality = c("NA", "NA"))
```

My desired df3 is like

```
df3 <- data.frame(Date = c("28/04/2010", "18/03/2010","10/05/2010", "22/11/2010", "05/07/2010", "07/09/2010", "26/09/2010","16/01/2010", "10/05/2010", "22/11/2010", "05/07/2010", "07/09/2010"),
                  HolidayType = c("MUNICIPAL","ESTADUAL", "NACIONAL", "NACIONAL", "OPTIONAL", "OPTIONAL", "MUNICIPAL","ESTADUAL","NACIONAL", "NACIONAL", "OPTIONAL", "OPTIONAL"),
                  State = c("AC", "AC", "MG", "MG"),
                  Municipality = c("Acrelândia", "Acrelândia", "Acrelândia", "Acrelândia", "Acrelândia", "Acrelândia","Belo Horizonte","Belo Horizonte", "Belo Horizonte","Belo Horizonte","Belo Horizonte","Belo Horizonte"))
```

I am using the following code that is almost doing what is needed but leaving NA in the "Municipality" column, except from the value from df. What to do in this case?

```
# initialize an empty dataframe to store the merged result
df3 <- data.frame(Date = character(),
                  HolidayType = character(),
                  State = character(),
                  Municipality = character(),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# loop through unique Municipality values in df and merge matching rows from df1
for (m in unique(df$Municipality)) {
  df_sub <- df[df$Municipality == m, ]
  df1_sub <- df1[df1$State %in% df_sub$State, ]
  df2_sub <- df2
  df4_sub <- df4
  df3 <- rbind(df3, df_sub, df1_sub, df2_sub, df4_sub)
}

# sort by date and reset row names
df3 <- df3[order(as.Date(df3$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")), ]
```

Comment: Could you clarify/explain the logic in creating `df3`?

Comment: The information of df1, df2 and df4 applies to all elements of df, and I would like to have an outcome like df3. My code posted does that, except Municipality column which leave all elements merged/rbind from df1, df2 and df4 as blank ("NA")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't make it very clear, but I *think* what you want is a dataframe of holidays and all places they're observed, based on whether they're municipal, state, national, or "optional" holidays, with optional holidays treated the same as national holidays. If that's right, I would use a series of joins for each holiday type with unique places, then bind together. Using dplyr:

```r
library(dplyr)  # >= v1.1.0 for `cross_join()`

# create df of unique places
places <- distinct(df, State, Municipality)

# municipal holidays are already associated with the correct places
municipal_hdys <- df
# for state holidays, join by `State`
state_hdys <- left_join(select(df1, Date, HolidayType, State), places)
# for national and optional holidays, use a cross-join to associate with all places
national_hdys <- cross_join(select(df2, Date, HolidayType), places)
optional_hdys <- cross_join(select(df4, Date, HolidayType), places)

# bind it all together and sort
bind_rows(municipal_hdys, state_hdys, national_hdys, optional_hdys) %>% 
  arrange(as.Date(Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

```
         Date HolidayType State   Municipality
1  16/01/2010    ESTADUAL    MG Belo Horizonte
2  18/03/2010    ESTADUAL    AC     Acrelândia
3  28/04/2010   MUNICIPAL    AC     Acrelândia
4  10/05/2010    NACIONAL    AC     Acrelândia
5  10/05/2010    NACIONAL    MG Belo Horizonte
6  05/07/2010    OPTIONAL    AC     Acrelândia
7  05/07/2010    OPTIONAL    MG Belo Horizonte
8  07/09/2010    OPTIONAL    AC     Acrelândia
9  07/09/2010    OPTIONAL    MG Belo Horizonte
10 26/09/2010   MUNICIPAL    MG Belo Horizonte
11 22/11/2010    NACIONAL    AC     Acrelândia
12 22/11/2010    NACIONAL    MG Belo Horizonte
```

Comment: Thank you, however, your code brings Error: 'cross_join' is not an exported object from 'namespace:dplyr' - I used packageVersion('dplyr') which returns ‘1.0.10’

Comment: @MarceloRibeiro, I believe that's why zephryl commented in the code `# >= v1.1.0 for \`cross_join()\``

Comment: @MarceloRibeiro yes, you’d need to update to the latest version by running `install.packages("dplyr")`. Also can you confirm that my understanding of your goal is right? If so (or if not) you may want to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you, I have to reinstall some times dplyr to get it done, so to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way. It is by hand:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bind_rows(df[1,], df2[1,], df2, df4, df[2,], df1[2,], df2, df4) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~na_if(., "NA"))) %>% 
  fill(c(State, Municipality), .direction = "down")

     Date HolidayType State   Municipality
1  28/04/2010   MUNICIPAL    AC     Acrelândia
2  10/05/2010    NACIONAL    AC     Acrelândia
3  10/05/2010    NACIONAL    AC     Acrelândia
4  22/11/2010    NACIONAL    AC     Acrelândia
5  05/07/2010    OPTIONAL    AC     Acrelândia
6  07/09/2010    OPTIONAL    AC     Acrelândia
7  26/09/2010   MUNICIPAL    MG Belo Horizonte
8  16/01/2010    ESTADUAL    MG Belo Horizonte
9  10/05/2010    NACIONAL    MG Belo Horizonte
10 22/11/2010    NACIONAL    MG Belo Horizonte
11 05/07/2010    OPTIONAL    MG Belo Horizonte
12 07/09/2010    OPTIONAL    MG Belo Horizonte
```